# Increment a column when using a UNION clause

Tags: sql, hive

I have the following query :

```
select row_number() over (order by 1) as id,"-1" AS StatusCode,"Not informed" AS StatusLibelle
union
select row_number() over (order by 1) as id,"0" AS StatusCode,"Off" AS StatusLibelle
union
select row_number() over (order by 1) as id,"1" AS StatusCode,"On" AS StatusLibelle
```

When I try to query it on hive, I get the following result

```
id StatusCode StatusLibelle
1  -1         Not informed
1   0         Off
1   1         On
```

This is my expected output, the id column should be incremented:

```
id StatusCosqlde StatusLibelle
1  -1         Not informed
2   0         Off
3   1         On
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
select row_number() over (order by 1) as id,"-1" AS StatusCode,"Not informed" AS StatusLibelle
union
select row_number() over (order by 1) + 1 as id,"0" AS StatusCode,"Off" AS StatusLibelle
union
select row_number() over (order by 1) + 2 as id,"1" AS StatusCode,"On" AS StatusLibelle
```

Comment: Worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `row_number()`?

```
select 1 as id, -1 AS StatusCode, 'Not informed' AS StatusLibelle
union all
select 2 as id, 0 AS StatusCode, 'Off' AS StatusLibelle
union all
select 3 as id, 1 AS StatusCode, 'On' AS StatusLibelle
```

In addition, there is no reason to use `UNION`, which incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  And, `StatusCode` looks like a number, so return it as a number, not a string.